# Getting error while importing my old project to Android studio 2.0

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I just download the latest Android studio and trying to import my old project which was good with the last version. But I am getting

`Error:org.gradle.tooling.BuildActionExecuter.withCancellationToken(Lorg/gradle/tooling/CancellationToken;)Lorg/gradle/tooling/BuildActionExecuter;`

I am also getting this error when I am creating new projects.

Any suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: then what is the problem occure.

Comment: As 'Method : 1"- I didn't find any files with "-*-1.8 files" names

Comment: and for Method 2 . It display path also show you can find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just deleted all the file from my install directory and re-extracted the file, the problem gone.

Answer (score 0):

## Method : 1.

1.Close Android Studio

2.go to android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib

3.Delete (or better move them somewhere to have a backup) all
gradle-*-1.8 files

4. Start Android Studio again and rebuild/refresh.

It should work

## Method : 2.

Choose another path of gradle in:

```
File --> settings --> Build,Execution --> Build Tools --> Gradle
```

If you use of ver 2 select path of installed android studio and select gradle Folder.

[image]

Comment: My Gradle home is 
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-2.10
And rest are same as you showed.

should I delete "gradle-2.10"?

Comment: @Sudarshan I think you get the solution